# How to refresh files in 'user stage' in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am developing a dimensional model using pandas and writing df to snowflake tables.

I am using the Snowflake PUT and COPY commands to upload data.

PUT command writes your data (in my case csv) from your local machine to a stage in Snowflake. There are two types of stages, internal and external. Internal stages are further of 3 types - User (allocated to each snowflake user by default), table (by default, each snowflake table has an associated storage) named (user can create a named storage).

I am using `user` stage for my PUT operation.

The problem: Files in `user` stage do not update/refresh when I save my data with same filename. If you save a file with same name more than once, it does not get updated in the local snowflake stage.

Found this on snowflake forum regarding refreshing `external` stages - https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009a7I9kSAE/how-does-a-stage-recognize-changes-especially-for-parquet
Excerpt: "Unless you explicitly specify FORCE = TRUE as one of the copy options, the command ignores staged data files that were already loaded into the table. To reload the data, you must either specify FORCE = TRUE or modify the file and stage it again, which generates a new checksum. It should be same for all types of files."

Although it is not applicable in my case, this solution nevertheless has another issue. This setting duplicates data.

From Snowflake docs:

```
FORCE = TRUE | FALSE
Definition
Boolean that specifies to load all files, 
regardless of whether they’ve been loaded previously 
and have not changed since they were loaded. 
Note that this option reloads files, 
potentially duplicating data in a table.
```

There is actually a way to edit properties of `named` and `external` stages using the `ALTER STAGE` command - you can specify the FORCE param for AUTO-REFRESH.

But there is no option for refreshing user stages!

Is there a way to refresh them or are user stages just not meant for this?

Comment: You are mixing up a few different concepts here and I'm not following what your issue is.  When you say that files do not refresh in stage, what do you mean?  When you upload a new file to stage it should overwrite it.  When you then run a copy command, if you are using the same file name, it won't load into the table, because Snowflake thinks the file has already been loaded.  FORCE will allow the copy of the same filename again.  If you don't truncate the table first, it will reload the same file.  Are you trying to get a table to be refresh based on the contents of a single file?

Comment: If you are, then you might want to consider external tables.  And why use PUT and COPY when using pandas?  If you use pandas, you can write directly to a table using the Snowflake python connector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am new to the database space, apologies for the confusion - this is all I could understand from the documentation. You are right, I am trying to refresh a table based on the contents of a single file.

Comment: I tried writing using Snowflake python connector both using write_pandas and sqlalchemy df.to_sql with method=pd_writer. Ran into issues with both - With write_pandas, I could not find an option to append records to an existing table. There is an option to auto_create a table and overwrite an existing table but none to append data to a table.

Comment: With df.to_sql and conn=engine.connect(), I am getting AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor' error and with conn=engine.raw_connection(), I am getting a Database Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting error. Had to write my own function to create a table if doesn't exist and append if exists using PUT, DROP, CREATE and COPY.

Comment: @MikeWalton  Would really appreciate your input - I want to append records from a pandas dataframe to a snowflake table using a Python script. What would you recommend is the best way?

Comment: when you generate a new file, does it only have new records in it each time?

Comment: Yes,  the dataframe has new records but I am saving it as a csv with the same filename.

Comment: when you run your `copy into` command, use the FORCE option as you've documented in your question.  It is the correct way to load the new records.  The only way you'll get duplicates is if your new records file contains the same record as a previous file load.  You were on a good path there, the documentation just spooked you.

Comment: It spooked me so much so that I got triggered by Snowflake's API documentation 'was this helpful' note, and submitted my first angry feedback and first StackOverflow question today. Thanks a ton for restoring my faith in humanity!

Comment: Why not write each file with a different name (i.e. append a timestamp to a root name)? Then you won’t have this issue and you’ll have all your files, not just the latest one. BTW if this a real world build, and not just something you’re building for yourself, I’d probably use a named stage rather than a user stage

Comment: I am using user stage for local development and planning to use an external stage in the prod workflow. I would ideally like to skip using or managing the stage at all because I don't think I understand the concept completely yet. (to think of if there'd be storage costs associated with using stages)

Comment: Assuming you are using a Snowflake solution, there is no way to load data except via a stage; as this is the solution that is widely used I’m not sure why you think you wouldn’t use it. Obviously, if you use a 3rd party solution that connects directly to Snowflake (such as writing your own data loader in Python) you wouldn’t need to use a Stage. However, bulk loading using COPY INTO is the fastest way to load data, any solution that doesn’t use COPY INTO would be slower - if that’s an issue for you

Comment: The unknown for me is - What are the memory/storage limitations for snowflake stage?  do I need to explicitly handle files written to stage (by removing them periodically) or is that implicit?

Comment: There are effectively no limits on the volume of data a stage can hold. Best practises for managing files in a stage are covered in the documentation